# How can I correlate geolocation data?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, computer-science

A query .
I would like to cross two excel tables with 200 different geolocation points that register two vehicles that circulate through the city.
We want to see how many times the vehicles approach each other in an area of ​​approximately 1000 square meters, we want to use python for it...we think that with the clustering method we could do it but we haven't found how to do it yet...any idea guys ?

We have tried to use the clustering method without results